# How to get mixed text from v-html with unrendered tags and rendered tags

Tags: html, vuejs2

I get a text from elasticsearch,this is some keyword be surrounded with '', also some tags should only be displyed
formexample:
original text："/DocumentCMBCCNXXX"
rendered text: "/DocumentCMBCCNXXX";CMBCCNXXX displayed with red color
expect text: "/DocumentCMBCCNXXX ";CMBCCNXXX displayed with red color

expect v-html only render tag- to html

Answer (score 0):

resolved:

```js
content.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;").replace("&lt;span style='color:red'&gt;","<span style='color:red'").replace("&lt;/span&ge;","</span>")
```